# Convert single row to multiple rows in tableau based on some delimiter

Tags: tableau-api

I had a column with data as =>  a,b,c,d,e

I need to display(in worksheet) as

a

b

c

d

e

Note: need to be split based on ','

Do I need to to use calculation field or any other approach is there???

Went through split function but is used to generate new columns, I want to store in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

is this something that could work? (you said it's just a matter of visualization without altering data, right?)

[image]

I just created a CF like this:

```
REPLACE(value,",","
")
```

**EDIT**: since it seems that your need *involves a data manipulation* (you want multiple row instead of one) I think that the best way is using the split function even though, as you noticed, it will create new columns.

Otherwise if it's just a visualization need, you could use the solution posted before which shows your data ("a,b,c,d,e") in the same cell with the same horizontal alignment, just replacing commas with CR

Comment: how did you get that.. you are removing ','........ it will be "abcde" in  ur case

Comment: No they should be of different rows... you are keeping in a single row and showing vertical...... It is not what I required.. thanks

Comment: actually I replaced the comma with a CR (chr13) and it's just displayed horizontal (not vertical)... in other words you need a sort of manipulation on your data and it's NOT JUST a matter of pure visualization